# What's wrong with my syntax for using this delegate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have this class where I define one or more functions that I want to pass as delegates:

```
class Sports
{
    public string judo(Player player, Venue venue)
    {
     //function body
    }
}
```

Here is a class with a method that can accept one of these functions as a delegate:

```
public class Player
{
    public void play(Venue venue,Func<Player,Venue,string> tournament)
    {
        string result = tournament(this,venue);
        //do something with result
    }
}
```

And here is a call to that method that passes in a suitable function:

```
public void playJudo(Player player,Venue venue)
{
    Sports sports=new Sports();
    player.play(venue,sports.judo(player,venue));
}
```

This doesn't compile; VS reports that the call to `player.play()` has invalid arguments.  I don't understand this--`judo()` returns a string, and the header for `play()` defines it as accepting a function that returns a string.  What's wrong here?

Comment: That's because `Sports.judo` returns `string`, not `Func<Player,Venue,string>`

Comment: What I think you want is `player.play(venue, sports.judo);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using delegates in a parameter like `Func<T1, T2, T3>` there, you actually want to pass the *function* as the parameter, not the *results* of the function. Applying the function call operator, parens, *calls* the function. Try something like:

```
public void playJudo(Player player, Venue venue)
{
    Sports sports = new Sports();
    player.play(venue, sports.judo);
}
```

Comment: That compiled, but I'm puzzled: how does this work if I haven't indicated which arguments are being passed to `sports.judo()`?  Couldn't there be another instance of `Player` in the body of `playJudo()` that I might want to pass in instead?

Comment: oh wait, i see, it gets it because `player` called `play()` and that's the instance that gets passed in.

Comment: That argumemnts are passed when you call `tournament()` in the `play()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a the return value of sports.judo which is a string. Make  public string judo(Player player, Venue venue) a static method or pass just sports.judo